# How to append a variable inside another vaiable name in liquid html

Tags: shopify, liquid

Here is the code:

```
{% for i in (0..5) %}
  {% assign product = recommendations.top_related_products_{{i}}.products[0].title %}
  {{ product }}
{% endfor %}
```

This code throws the error `Liquid error: Cannot read property '0' of null`

I have 6 arrays under recommendation like `top_related_products_0...5`.

How do I print the title variable which is inside the `top_related_products_0..5`?

Comment: what's the content of recommendations.top_related_products ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a string containing the variable name, then use [square bracket notation](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle#attributes-handle) to access it.

For example:

```
{% for i in (0..5) %}
  {% capture related_products %}top_related_products_{{i}}{% endcapture %}
  {{ recommendations[related_products].products.first.title }}
{% endfor %}
```